# If $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $a_{n+1}+a_n\to0$ then $a_n\to0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of numbers such that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} (a_{n+1}+a_n)=0}$. 
>   I want to show that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n=0}$.

I have done the following:

Since the sequence $(a_n)$ is decreasing, we have that $$a_{n+1}\leq a_n \Rightarrow a_{n+1}-a_n\leq 0$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(a_{n+1}-a_n)\leq 0 &\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(a_{n+1}+a_n-a_n-a_n)\leq 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(a_{n+1}+a_n-2a_n)\leq 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(a_{n+1}+a_n)-2\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n\leq 0 \\
&\Rightarrow -2\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n\leq 0
\end{align}$$

Is this correct so far?

How could we continue?

Or is there an other way to get the desired result?

Comment: For a simple approach, note and use the double inequality $0\leqslant a_n\leqslant\frac12(a_n+a_{n-1})$.

Comment: @ DId Why is $a_n\ge 0$?

Comment: Why does the first inequality stand? How do we know that $a_n\geq 0$ ? @Did

Comment: Because $(a_n)$ is decreasing hence if $a_n\leqslant-c$ with $c>0$ for any $n$ then $a_k+a_{k+1}\leqslant-2c$ for every $k\geqslant n$, which makes the limit $a_k+a_{k+1}\to0$ impossible.

Comment: @Did How did you get $a_n \leq -c$ for $c > 0$? Consider the decreasing sequence $a_n=2^{-n}$. Is that true for $c=1$?

Comment: @NobleMushtak This comment answers the question by Mary "how do we know that every $a_n$ is nonnegative", assuming that $a_n$ is negative for some $n$ and reaching a contradiction.

Comment: if $(a_n)$ converges, it converges to $0$. and a decreasing sequence has to converge in $\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\}$

Comment: @Did Ah...OK. That makes sense.

Comment: ...And @N.S. does it more directly.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

Since $a_n$ is decreasing you have

$$   a_{n+1}+a_n \leq a_n +a_n \leq a_n +a_{n-1}$$

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

By dividing the last inequality by $-2$, we clearly get the following:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n \geq 0$$

To prove that this is equal to $0$, we now only need to prove that:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n \leq 0$$

Now, if we shift the sequence to be $a_{n+1}$ rather than $a_n$, then we have not changed what value it converges to as $n \to +\infty$ because we just shifted the sequence. Thus, we have the following:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n$$

Thus, we will prove instead that the left hand side of this equation is less than or equal to $0$, which will prove the whole theorem. Now, to do this, we will show that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1} \leq \lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n+a_{n+1}$ or something of the like. To do this, we need to somehow relate $a_{n+1}$ to $a_n+a_{n+1}$ in an inequality. Let's try breaking up $a_{n+1}$ into two parts:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac 1 2(a_{n+1}+a_{n+1})$$

Now, as you said, $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$. Thus, if we substitute the second $a_{n+1}$ with $a_n$ in the right hand side, we get an expression greater than or equal to the left-hand side, meaning, as [@Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636514/the-limit-is-equal-to-0#comment3337076_1636514) said.
$$a_{n+1} \leq \frac 1 2(a_{n+1}+a_n)$$

Thus, the limit as these two expressions as $n \to +\infty$ have the same relation:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1} \leq \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac 1 2(a_{n+1}+a_n)$$

Bring the $\frac 1 2$ out of the limit on the right-hand side:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1} \leq \frac 1 2\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1}+a_n$$

It is given that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1}+a_n=0$, so the right-hand side is just $0$:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_{n+1} \leq 0$$

Thus, by showing that this limit is less than or equal to $0$ and using the inequality that we derived from your work at the top, we have:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = 0$$

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help!